# App Crashing When Relaunching

Tags: iphone, objective-c

When I hard exit (double click home and minus) and then relaunch app it is freezing up.

The Console shows this:

[app directory path .....]has changed; re-reading symbols.

I think it may have to do with this code in my appdelagate.m

```
- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application
{
    [self saveCode];
}

- (void)saveCode
{
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);  
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"routine.plist"];
    [NSArray writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
}
```

Comment: Is that a typo, or are you calling `[NSArray writeToFile:atomically:]` like that?  If it isn't a typo, that's your problem.  Replace `NSArray` with the name of your array variable.

Comment: Hello, I am also facing the same issue.Having some "performSelector" in applicationWillResignActive method will cause the "failed to resume" crash after re-lunching app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First: saving a plist to populate a UITableViewController is a really tedious way to save data persistently and an inconsistent one as you may have realized, I would recommend that you use [Core Data](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/DataManagement/Conceptual/iPhoneCoreData01/Introduction/Introduction.html) instead.

Second: Run the debugger (before launching your app) and find any line of text that's shown in black (grey lines are for methods called by the os and the cocoa layer, black ones are for your own methods). The debugger can be run via Run > Debugger or `Command + Shift + Y`.

Comment: I haven't learned CoreData yet and don't want to waste time learning it and holding up my app.  Therefore I will learn it and implement it into the app after it releases.

Comment: And I posted in the question what the debugger came up with.

Comment: That's console output, you need debugger output. And good luck with the implementing core data after release thing

Comment: About the CoreData, are you saying it will be difficult to do after releaseing?

Comment: Unfortunately yes, a little bit, but if you have the will to do it and are not lazy enough to go through the process, then it shouldn't be a big deal

Comment: yah I get it, well I'm not sure if i should do it now or after.  My data model is relatively simple I think so I'm not sure if I will even need it at all.  I do want to have user accounts though.

Comment: Well, my advise would be to check out the tutorial I pointed you to on my answer, read it, analyze it, and then decide whether you want to implement it or if you are comfortable with what you have now. The reason I (and many other people, I believe) prefer Core Data is that once you get the grasp of it, it's really easy and simple to use (even simpler than pure SQL) with the added bonus that it is in fact a SQLite database.

Answer (score 0):

The similar kind of crashing issue - on quick relaunch is being faced when I use location manager in the application. The case is : my application quits on pressing home button rather than going into the background in iPhone 4. And on iPhone 3G (where no background processing is supported) the case is same - it crashes on relaunch [atleast it seems like a crash].

If we wait even 1 second to relaunch the app, it does not crash.